# Unable to send a photo from React Native to Cloudinary

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload images to Cloudinary from my React Native app, but I'm getting the "400 Bad Request" saying the image I'm sending is ""x-cld-error": "Unsupported source URL".

ImageUpload.js

```js
    const pickImage = async () => {
        let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
            mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
            allowsEditing: true,
            aspect: [4, 3],
            quality: 1
        })

        if (!result.cancelled) {
            setImageSource(result.uri);
        }
    }
```

I'm currently using the `ImagePicker` from `expo-image-picker`. I'm taking the `imageSource` I've obtained from above and appending it to data before sending it to Cloudinary. The `result.uri` shows the URL of the picture from the iOS simulator.

CreatePost.js

```js
    const uploadFile = async () => {
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', imageSource);
        data.append('upload_preset', 'test_folder')

        const res = await fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/{my_cloudinary}/image/upload', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: data,
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        })

        const file = await res.json()
        setImage(file.secure_url)
        setLargeImage(file.eager[0].secure_url)
    }
```

When I console.log `res`, it shows that the status is 400.

Comment: Could you please log and include the value of `imageSource` in the same function you're performing the Upload request to Cloudinary? I ask that because when this error is returned it includes the start of the source that was used, but in your question, that's not included. For example, `Unsupported source URL: data:;base64,` or `Unsupported source URL: Object(...`.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using ajax. For example here:

```html
<h1>Upload to Cloudinary with FormData</h1>
<div>
<p>

Set your cloud name in the API URL in the code:  "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<strong>&lt;cloud&nbsp;name&gt;</strong>/image/upload" before running the example.
</p>
</div>
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="AJAXSubmit(this); return false;">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Upload example</legend>
    <p>
      <label for="upload_preset">Unsigned upload Preset: <input type="text" name="upload_preset">(set it <a href="https://cloudinary.com/console/settings/upload#upload_presets">here</a>)</label>
    </p>
    <p>
      <label >Select your photo:
      <input type="file" name="file"></label>
    </p>
    
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
    <img id="uploaded">
    <div id="results"></div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shirlymanor/s1hou7zr/